# compile php 5.4.5 with mongo driver

Tags: php, compilation, php-mongodb

Now I have installed php 5.3.* via apt-get on my Ubuntu PC, but I need to work with 5.4.5 for some issue. 
According to this reason, I try to compile and install new version php 5.4.5 with mongo driver into separete place:
I did next steps:

```
sudo su
cd /opt
tar xfz php-5.4.5.tar.gz
cd php-5.4.5
./configure --prefix=/opt/php545 --enable-phar --with-config-file-path=/opt/php545/php.ini
make & make install
```

after above commands I had got working php:

```
/opt/php545/bin/php -v
PHP 5.4.5 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2012 09:04:56) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

after it I did next:

```
/opt/php545/bin/pecl install mongo
```

and it return me

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/php545/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.2.12
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mongo.so" to php.ini
```

I added  into /opt/php545/php.ini next line

```
extension=/opt/php545/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so
```

but mongo not loaded as module:

```
/opt/php545/bin/php -m | grep mongo
!!!Nothing here!!!
```

What did I do wrong?

PS:

```
 /opt/php545/bin/php -i | grep php.ini
```

return

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/php545/php.ini
```

(php.ini seting up properly)

Comment: What's result of if just do `extension=mongo.so`?

Answer (score 0):

php config doesn't accept absolute path for extensions line, please use extension_dir.

Comment: Tried extension=mongo.so and extension_dir=/opt/php545/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525 with extension=mongo.so same bad result.

Comment: I could see how one might apply this as an answer if there was an example or something to go with it, but this "answer" if you will call it that, is better suited as a comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Not load the extension from php.ini, load from ini file parsed as follows:

```
 nano /usr/local/php-5.x.xx/php.d/mongo.ini
```

x.xx is you PHP version.

Then load the extension:

```
 ;Enable mongo extension module
 extension=mongo.so
 mongo.default_port=27017
```

save with ctrl + o and close white crtl + x

Then restart the services:

```
 service php-fpm restart 
 service httpd restart
```

// php-fpm If it has

So you should already loaded.